# Access Now.js and express.js from the web folder

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

Where do I have to install Now.js and express.js to access it from the web folder?

My web-folder is located here: **/var/www/virtual/domain.com/htdocs** and I'm using **node v.0.6.6**

But when I install now.js with "npm install now" in the root folder, I get an error when I want to run my server.js file:

```
var html = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname+'/index.html');
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res){
  res.end(html);
});
server.listen(8080);

var nowjs = require("now");
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);

everyone.now.distributeMessage = function(message){
  everyone.now.receiveMessage(this.now.name, message);
};
```

**Error: Cannot find module 'now'**

Do I have to set the node_path somewhere? Or do I have to place the now.js file into my webfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM will install `now` and `express` in the folder where you are when you execute the install command. NPM will create a folder called `node_modules` and put them there. If you have a file you need to run named server.js, make sure it's at the same level as node_modules.

If you just want to install them locally and use them everywhere do it like so:

`npm install now -g`

The g flag stands for 'globally'.

Comment: installing it in the root folder with the g flag didn't work, but installing it in my webfolder did, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you wish for the package to be available globally then you should do:

```
npm install -g now
```

If not, make sure you're in the same folder as your `server.js` file and then run:

```
npm install now
```

(as you did before)

See http://npmjs.org/doc/install.html